# How to get first and last commit from git from a user

Tags: git

I was wondering how I could get my first an last git message commits from a git project?

My idea was to do a git log and use grep to catch the first and last row from a user, is there any elegant way of doing so?

Comment: First and last in what sense? Topological or chronological? In either case, there may not be a unique first commit and a unique last commit.

Comment: There are may be multiple topological orderings, but I think chronologically there will exist unique first and last commits

Comment: @chepner That's realistic, but strictly speaking, there may be multiple commits with exactly the same timestamp.

Comment: Depends on your clock resolution :) But I think it's safe to assume that commits in a single branch are ordered chronologically, and distinct commits that are branch heads are unlikely to have identical timestamps.

Comment: first and last commit in commit order

Comment: @haskellguy Commits can be ordered in two ways: *chronological*, and (because they form a directed acyclic graph), *topological*. However, two commits may have the same timestamp; also, in general, a DAG doesn't have a unique topological sort. Therefore, whether you want to sort the commits in chronological or topological order, there may not be a commit that is unambiguously first (or last).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--author` flag with a regular expression that matches your name (which in practice might just be your name):

```
git log --author "Firstname Lastname"
```

You can simply use the `-n` option to get the last commit.

```
git log --author "Firstname Lastname" -n 1  # Last commit
```

The first commit is a little trickier; you can reverse the order with the `--reverse` flag, but it would be applied *after* `-n 1`, so you'll just have to post-process the output, for example,

```
git log --author "Firstname Lastname" --reverse | awk '/^commit/ { x+=1 } x>1 {exit}; {print}'
```

This assumes a chronological ordering. In the presence of multiple branches, there may not be a unique last commit, and it's possible that there isn't even a unique first commit.

Comment: Just a typo; I forgot a pair of braces in the `awk` script.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Medium answer: see `git help log` under the section Pretty Formats, where you could define a format string to produce a JSON object for each commit. Long answer: post another question if you need help figuring out how to define such a format :)